# get all records without fulfilling a condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have these config in oracle:

```
DEF
===
NAMEJOB
ID_JOB
ID_TABLE
....

VARIABLE
========
ID_JOB
ID_TABLE
NAME
VALUE
....
```

Registers examples:

```
DEF
===
NAMEJOB="APPLE"
ID_JOB=1
ID_TABLE=1


NAMEJOB="HOUSE"
ID_JOB=2
ID_TABLE=2


VARIABLE
========
ID_JOB=1
ID_TABLE=1
NAME="COLOR"
VALUE="GREEN"

ID_JOB=1
ID_TABLE=1
NAME="SIZE"
VALUE="SMALL"


ID_JOB=2
ID_TABLE=2
NAME="COLOR"
VALUE="BROWN"

......
```

I would like to get all registers that don't have "NAME=SIZE" IN THE TABLE VARIABLE. So the output should be:

```
ID_JOB=2
ID_TABLE=2
NAMEJOB=HOUSE
```

If I make a where with job_id and table_id shows me all registers. Someone could help me please? Thanks and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NOT EXISTS should help you

```
SELECT ID_JOB,
ID_TABLE,
NAMEJOB
FROM DEF d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM VARIABLE v WHERE d.ID_JOB=v.id_job AND
d.ID_TABLE=v.ID_TABLE and v.NAME = 'SIZE')
```

[image]

Comment: Strange.. works for me...Please edit your question and enter your code so I can see what is going on.